# Javascript play button for animation

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript animation using Raphael which is in an external file linked to HTML. I would like to have the user click on the animation to start it rather than the animation starting as soon as the page is loaded.

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("animation"), 800, 600);
    var img = paper.image("backimg.jpg",0,0,950,600);
    img.attr({"clip-rect":"0,0,800,600"});
    img.addEventListener("click",function() {
      var squ = paper.rect(-100,50,100,100);
      squ.attr("fill", "#ffffff");

      squ.animate({transform: "T450,0"}, 2000, "ease-out", explode);
      var cir2 = paper.rect(400,100,1,1);

      function explode(){
        cir2.attr("fill","#f00");
        cir2.animate({ transform:'s100' }, 2000);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting the animation to play when its initial state frame is clicked?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: To clarify, there is an image with an animation. The solution is to set a click event handler on the image and call the animation function when the event fires. I'll answer ASAP but I have to write a paper for school first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you OP for providing the code. The Raphael JS library uses SVG so the only applicable solution is to set a click event listener to the parent node which, in this case, it the element with an id of `animation`.

Examine the code snippet:

```js
//https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg

window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var animation = document.getElementById('animation');
    var paper = new Raphael(animation, 800, 600);
    var img = paper.image("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg",0,0,950,600);
    img.attr({"clip-rect":"0,0,800,600"});
    animation.addEventListener("click",function() {
      var squ = paper.rect(-100,50,100,100);
      squ.attr("fill", "#ffffff");

      squ.animate({transform: "T450,0"}, 2000, "ease-out", explode);
      var cir2 = paper.rect(400,100,1,1);

      function explode(){
        cir2.attr("fill","#f00");
        cir2.animate({ transform:'s100' }, 2000);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js"></script>
<div id="animation"></div>
```

Hopefully this is helpful.

Comment: I get a 'undefined is not a function' error for this line       img.addEventListener("click",function() {

Comment: @HarryRollings Could you embed a code snippet in your question with all the code? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I've added part of the animation to the question

Comment: @HarryRollings My answer is updated. Examine and run the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

if you want doing it using a button it should look like this:

```
<button onclick="myAnimation()">Play Animation</button>
```

where **myAnimation** is the name of the function that runs the animation.